# TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined bcryptjs session

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, undefined

I am currently implementing the authentication part for my project, the problem is when I was done with the code that I tried to implement for the authentication I got this error 
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

I don't know what to do and I know that user is undefined but I don't know what the next step is and I am basically stuck, I would be very grateful if you could take a look at the code and try to see how it is solvable. 
I am using bcryptjs in my auth controller btw, but I hope this code is enough to see what's going on and even solve it.

```
require('dotenv').config({path: "node.env"});
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const flash = require("connect-flash");

const session = require("express-session");
const MongoDBStore = require("connect-mongodb-session")(session);
const errorController = require('./controllers/error');

const mongodb_uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const app = express();
const csrf = require("csurf");
const User = require("./models/user");

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: mongodb_uri,
    collection: "sessions"
});

const csrfProtection = csrf();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
const blogRoutes = require("./routes/blog");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
        },
        store: store,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,

    })
)

app.use(flash());
app.use(csrfProtection);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.user._id) {
        return next();
    }
    User.findById(req.session.user._id)
    .then(user => {
        req.user = user;
        next();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isauthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
    res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
    next();
});

app.use("/admin", adminRoutes);
app.use(blogRoutes);


app.use(errorController.get404);

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

mongoose.connect(mongodb_uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("listening to port 3000")
})
```

I'm expecting everything to work and I don't quite see what the problem is, I even followed the structure of a course instructor.

Comment: Check if req.session has user in it or not

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   if (!req.session.user._id) {
       return next();
   }
   User.findById(req.session.user._id)
   .then(user => {
       req.user = user;
       next();
   })
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

What you intended to do actually:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return next();
  }
  User.findById(req.session.user._id)
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return next();
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Your got to first check `req.session.user` (remove `._id`).
Then you forgot to check in `.then(user => {...})` to look for `user` again,
that is:
 `if(!user){return next();}`